# Will robots.txt block crawling things like menu and footer links?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

If I am blocking a page called pay.php, google won't crawl this page. But what about the links that are on this page as default as menu and footer links? Will these links also be blocked from crawling?

But I see that only one page is getting restricted by google bot other than pay.php page, and not other links. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

If the links are linked to only from the page you blocked, they will not be crawled. Of course, these links are probably linked to and crawled from other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Answer lies in your line `If I am blocking a page called pay.php, google won't crawl this page`. If search engines doesn't even crawl that page it won't then find any links etc on that particular page.